# Inside a decorator-class, access instance of the class which contains the decorated method

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following decorator, which saves a configuration file after a method decorated with `@saveconfig` is called:

```
class saveconfig(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.f(object, *args)
        # Here i want to access "cfg" defined in pbtools
        print "Saving configuration"
```

I'm using this decorator inside the following class. After the method `createkvm` is called, the configuration object `self.cfg` should be saved inside the decorator:

```
class pbtools()
    def __init__(self):
        self.configfile = open("pbt.properties", 'r+')
        # This variable should be available inside my decorator
        self.cfg = ConfigObj(infile = self.configfile)

    @saveconfig
    def createkvm(self):
        print "creating kvm"
```

My problem is that i need to access the object variable `self.cfg` inside the decorator `saveconfig`. A first naive approach was to add a parameter to the decorator which holds the object, like `@saveconfig(self)`, but this doesn't work.

How can I access object variables of the method host inside the decorator? Do i have to define the decorator inside the same class to get access?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make your decorator class behave as a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) to be able to access the instance:

```
class saveconfig(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args):
            print "Saving configuration"
            print instance.cfg
            return self.f(instance, *args)
        return wrapper
```

Your code passes `object` as first parameter to `self.f()`, where it *should* pass the `pbtools` instance.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `object` as `self` to the decorated method. The thing is, you can't easily get `self` because Python sees the decorated method, which is now an objects, and doesn't consider it a method (that should be passed `self` when called - or, more generally, that should work as a property returning a bound method). You can work around this, as pointed out by @Sven Marnach.

However, you could easily rewrite this decorator without a class, using a closure (is a bit shorter and also solves the above problem):

```
def saveconfig(f):
    @functools.wraps(f) # to preserve name, docstring, etc.
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): # **kwargs for compability with functions that use them
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        # save config
    return wrapper
```

Other notes:

- Terminology mixup: There is no class variable in the example. A class variable would be `x = ...` indented as far as the method definitions and be shared between all instances (specifically, it would be an attribute of the object that is `pbtools`) - everything on `self` is an instance attribute.
- At class definition time (when you define methods, apply decorators, etc.) there is no `self`!

Comment: The code won't run any more if you omit the `object` parameter.  Try it.

Comment: @Sven: Only with the class-based approach, it seems. You propably need to convince Python to treat that object as a method (so a getter that passes `self` implicitly is generated) =/ Well, yet another reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple function for what you want:

```
def saveconfig(f):
    # this method replaces the decorated, so `self` will be the pbtools instance
    def wrapped(self, *args):
        f(self, *args)
        # Here i want to access "cfg" defined in pbtools
        print "Saving configuration", self.cfg
    return wrapped
```

If `saveconfig` must be a class then you need Sven's solution.

Comment: Misses `functools.wraps`. Also, it breaks for nullary functions (e.g. non-methods without arguments) and has a misleading name for the first argument for non-methods in general - better leave `self` in `args` ;) (And after these changes, it's pretty much what I already posted)