# How to write a one function tool that does a check on a class variable in cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I can't find the way to make it work. I think the problem is about how to pass the class variable or the class reference (self) to the function. The code is similar to the following:

```
def isconnected(classref):
    if not classref.serialObject:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError("403 Forbidden")

cherrypy.tools.isconnected = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', isconnected)
```

And then in the app class, it should be used like this:

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.serialObject = None

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.isconnected(self.serialObject)
    def serialVRead(self):
        # code here
        pass
```

In other words, I basically want to check if the resource is available before calling the normal handler. Also, I need it to be a tool since I have a few other methods that I want to decorate like that as well.

Besides, I'd also like to know if I can prevent the normal handler to execute using a different solution than raising the HTTPError exception. I tried with returning True or False without success.

Please, let me know if this is possible or if there is a better way to achieve this. Thank you.

PD. I am running Cherrypy's latest version (3.3 I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can retrieve the instance that current handler belongs to from `cherrypy.serving.request.handler` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


def isconnected():
  instance = cherrypy.serving.request.handler.callable.__self__
  if not instance.instanceAttr:
    raise cherrypy.HTTPError("403 Forbidden")

cherrypy.tools.isconnected = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', isconnected)


class App:

  instanceAttr = None


  def __init__(self):
    self.instanceAttr = 123

  @cherrypy.tools.isconnected()
  @cherrypy.expose  
  def index(self):
    return '''foo'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

2) Generally in Python, decorators operate on functions before they become instance methods. If you need to access to an instance in decorator you need to implement [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) (see [question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4987471/2072035)). Because a CherryPy Tool builds upon decorators but has its own workflow, descriptor machinery may not work.

3) To conditionally avoid normal handler use `cherrypy._cptools.HandlerTool` ([docs](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.html#cherrypy._cptools.HandlerTool), [wiki](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/HandlerTool), [question with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065698/2072035)).

Comment: Great answer. Very informative. I think I will use the first and third points to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should interact with the serial object via a [CherryPy Plugin](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html) and communicate with something like:

```
serial_port = cherrypy.engine.publish('acquire_serial_port')
```

The idea of a plugin is to share a resource across requests, encapsulate and be reusable.

You can even mix that in a tool that references only to the published channels of the serial plugin.

Comment: I will look into it, but this still doesn't solve my problem. I need to perform a check before a handler is executed, and do the same check for a few other different handlers too. How can I do this with a plugin?

Comment: The tools are *specially* designed to execute something right before or after the handler. Check the documentation on extending CherryPy. Tool + Plugin is the *right* solution for something like this.

Comment: I know that and have gone over the docs quite thoroughly. My issue now is, by only using a tool, with my current implementation, how to pass the class variable (self.serialObject) into the decorator. The code above does not work of course, hence this question.